# osquery-python extension causing osqueryi errors

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, osquery

I have a newbie question about creating osquery extensions using osquery-python. I Created a small extension that gets some additional RPM info from my linux system. Following the instructions in the docs, I added the path to the extension in /etc/osquery/extensions.load to get it to autoload. I restarted osqueryd and I see the extension running using ps ax.

If I interactively run osqueryi, I can see the table and get data. It all works perfectly.

However, when I run an osqueryi command 'one-liner' such as :

```
osqueryi .tables
```

I get a bunch of the following errors with my output:

```
#INFO:thrift.transport.TSocket:Could not connect to /root/.osquery/shell.em
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 104, in open
    handle.connect(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
ERROR:thrift.transport.TSocket:Could not connect to any of ['/root/.osquery/shell.em']
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions are run in a separate process.  You can see the socket errors, which indicate the extension process cannot communicate with osquery process.  Make sure osqueryd or osqueryi is running. Link: [osquery doc page for extensions](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/osquery-sdk/).